# Is it not OK to ask if there is an API/command to do something?

Tags: support

My question looking for an API/command to manage the Windows Explorer "Quick Access" list was put on hold as too broad. I don't know how I can be more specific than this, but moderator's comment says (after chiding me for looking for free code/script writing service) that I must mention what I have tried so far, show my code, and explain where I am stuck. Actually it was not being able to find any command at all, rather than finding one and having trouble using it, that prompted me to post in superuser rather than stackoverflow.

I hope I don't sound like a whiner but I see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1390132/windows-bulk-rename-middle-filename-via-cli) with a question asking for a command to bulk remame file which the same moderator entertained with a detailed and thoughtful reply. Admittedly the question shows some work but it is literally just listing the `ren` command which does not have the functionality the user is looking for.

**Is there a forum on stackexchange where it is ok to request a api/command with certain functionality?**

Comment: And you have now commented that you are looking for an API. That is also off-topic. See the close reason.

Comment: @DavidPostill can you give me a hint how I could have improved my question? Or are you saying asking for a command / script is not a valid question? Because providing a script is exactly what you did for the other question about bulk rename :)

Comment: There is no way to improve your question. Asking for help with an existing script is not the same as asking for scripts where there is no script. Asking for APIs is off-topic as per the revised close reason for your question.

Comment: Well you could improve your question by having a go yourself and letting us know where you are stuck, but you do not seem willing to do that.

Comment: But there is no existing script the bulk-rename question! Mentioning that `ren` can only rename single file does not make it a script attempt

Comment: Sigh. He made an effort. You have made no effort at all.

Comment: It is not that I don't want to try myself, but I am *completely* out of idea where to even start? If I can bother you to look at some of my questions on stackoverflow, you will hopefully notice that I usually ask questions only with some work-in-progress code

Comment: "you have made no effort at all" -- well my efforts were focused on looking for a command that gives access to the Quick Access list but I could not find anything. Is there anything I can do to convince you that I did a thorough search?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). It says:

"Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: And I did mention that I searched and found only one discussion with no results. As I mentioned earlier, what can did to show that I did a thorough search?

Comment: @MiserableVariable - Since you seem completely lost, any quick access item would have a relevant would also appear in the registry.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you! During a second search I found the question [Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored) (the quality of which I shall not comment on :P) which gave exact location. Now I just need to figure out how to manipulate jump lists.

Comment: Miserable Variable - Without reading all comments, etc. & just your question, I think you simply need to find something (use Google, try things, etc.) & then when you find something or something close that work and you have some command you are having trouble with, show that and the command you are using. If you are looking for a command, API, tool, App, software, etc... then check out the [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) community as this is their purpose. It does seem odd a duplicate batch question received so many views though—that was definitely a dupe.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks! Software Recommendation is exactly what I needed. Another option would have been to close as a dupe of the other question which at least showed no more effort than mine. But I got reprimanded instead of saying forum instead of community.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know how I can be more specific than this, but moderator's comment says (after chiding me for looking for free code/script writing service) that I must mention what I have tried so far, show my code, and explain where I am stuck.

Indicating we are not a script writing service is not "being critical of" you, it's simply to inform you, questions seeking a script to do something are not within scope.

> Admittedly the question shows some work but it is literally just listing the ren command which does not have the functionality the user is looking for.

The difference between your question and your example is indeed the "work" and the additional effort, the other author provided.

> Is there a forum on Stack Exchange where it is ok to request an API/command with certain functionality?

Stack Exchange communities are not forums.  Questions that encourage discussions are typically closed.

Comment: Sorry for saying forum where I should have said community. Will try to be careful to use correct terms in future